# Keras, VAE: creating custom loss that computes the mean of every pixel value

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I am building a variational autoencoder that takes 28x28x1 images as input and generates 28x28x1 images as output, so each input and output sample can be represented as a vector with 784 entries. 
I want to add to the custom loss a term that computes the mean of the 784 values in every input and output image, and then computes the cross-entropy between those means.

My doubt is whether my code is computing the mean on every single input - output couple of images and not for the full set of input and output images. The complete data set I send as input has a shape (none, 28, 28, 1). I want the custom loss to compare the means for **each** couple of input and generated image.

This is the code I wrote:

```
def vae_loss(self, x, z_decoded):

    x_flat = K.flatten(x)
    z_decoded_flat = K.flatten(z_decoded)

    #usual cross entropy between input and output
    xent_loss = keras.metrics.binary_crossentropy(x_flat, z_decoded_flat)

    #kl divergence
    kl_loss = -5e-4 * K.mean(  
                    1 + z_log_var - K.square(z_mean) - K.exp(z_log_var), axis=-1)

    #cross-entropy between the means
    input = K.mean( K.flatten(x), axis=-1 )
    output = K.mean( K.flatten(z_decoded), axis=-1 )
    xent_means = keras.metrics.binary_crossentropy(input, output)



    return K.mean(xent_loss + kl_loss + xent_means)
```

The summary of the model is this:

[encoder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yJS6P.png)

[decoder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cn8Id.png)

Thank you very much in advance for any hint.

Comment: You can specify an `axis` argument in `K.means()` as well to specify the axis along the mean should be calculated.

Comment: Hi, thanks @Tinu. I put axis = -1 in K.means() to compute on the last dimension of the tensor. What I would like to understand is whether the "x" that Keras imports in the vae_loss is just a single input sample (28,28,1) (in which case I think the code I wrote should do what I expect it to) or if it is the full training data set (none, 28, 28 ,1).

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, the loss is calculated on the batch. Here (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53235029/issue-of-batch-sizes-when-using-custom-loss-functions-in-keras) is another post dealing with custom loss functions and batches. To verify this you could insert a simple `print` statement which tells you the shape of your input.